# Making measurements with oscilloscope on vehicle when earth and ground are common

Tags: ac, dc, oscilloscope

I'm trying to make a small system that reads my engine data on my old bus.

I've used an LM1815 and to be sure, I've checked the input signal and output of the lm1815.

I've placed my probes and ground of each closer as possible.

Because It's a motorhome, the earth of the inverter is connected to chassis ground (like in the Inverter datasheet).
So, if I remember, an Oscilloscope uses the earth as a reference, and in my case, earth = Ground (of my probe).
When I made my measurements, the input signal was really noisy and the logic signals out of the LM1815 had a little noise at the same time as input.(don't know which type of noise it is...)

My question is, is it possible that my earth = ground connection can cause this type of parasite? Can I set something on the oscilloscope to reduce noise? (I'm not an electronic engineer, I didn't find anything in the doc of the oscilloscope, and I'm not very familiar with this tool).
I've got many difficulties getting a readable trace of the input signal, it always moves right and left, for me it's the frequency that changes quickly but maybe theres another related problem.

For more context, my input sensor is a VR sensor, the ground is the direct battery one by the original wire of the dashboard, the trigger signal is set on CH2 (LM1815 output signal).
Let me know if you need more information.

EDIT: Add pictures of probing, general view, and detail views. On the plug the pin 25 is Ground and 19 Signal input from VR, on the second prob, I used the Grounded pin of resistor (ground is same as pin 25 of the main plug) and the output (Red wire, normaly connected to the Arduino) of LM1815.

EDIT 2: Yesturday, I've tested without all circuit to check the input signal only, it's better, but always with little spikes (clearly much easier to read, sometimes moves right/left but with higher trigger it reduce this effect). Even if the engine is of (last picture) I have some noise. When oscilloscope try to give me the frequency, he hit 100Mhz or few less... Maybe and ambient noise ?

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Probing matters. Please put a picture of your measurement setup i.e. how and where you attached the probes/clips.

Comment: Apart from the spikes, do the signals otherwise look ok? That is, is ch1 supposed to be a sinusoidal and ch2 a square wave?

Comment: I've added the pictures of probing.

@Lundin, yes otherwise the signals look good, exept that i can't be sure it's triggered when zero crossing because of the moves of the input signal. And yes CH1 is vr sensor so it's sinusoidal and CH2 is LM1815 logic output, so yes too, it's a square signal

Comment: Oh for the love of breadboard antenna nightmares... those pictures explain a lot. That's a spurious emission transceiver you've built. This thing needs to go, solder everything on a perfboard and _keep traces short and fixed closely to the board_. Breadboards are generally great for filling the electronics recycling bin but not much else.

Comment: Arf... What more logical thing with all those wires in the air... I don't have any perfboard but I'll try to found one. I'll hope it will help to have less spikes. I will try with the plug only just to test the input signal and see if it has less parasits

Comment: I've made a new measure of the input signal, see edit ;)